# Drupal 8 RESTful POST 400 Bad Request

Tags: 8

I'm trying to use the RESTful service for creating a node with Javascript using the script below, but I only receive a 400 (Bad Request) error. I have enabled all the formats and set permissions for authenticated users.

The reports shows the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: No route found for "GET /entity/node": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST) in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest() (line 163 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/comedinewithme/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php).
```

Do I need to set an authorization in the header? Isn't this what the csrf token is for though? And how should this be formatted? I'm completely lost!

```
function getCsrfToken(callback) {
  jQuery
    .get(Drupal.url('rest/session/token'))
    .done(function (data) {
      var csrfToken = data;
      callback(csrfToken);
    });
}

function postNode(csrfToken, node) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/entity/node?_format=hal_json',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json',
      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(node),
    success: function (node) {
      console.log(node);
    }
  });
}

var newNode = {
  _links: {
    type: {
      href: 'http://example.com/rest/type/node/article'
    }
  },
  type: {
    target_id: 'article'
  },
  title: {
    value: 'Example node title'
  }
}; 

getCsrfToken(function (csrfToken) {
  postNode(csrfToken, newNode);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: for the _links href I was using a relative URL instead of absolute.